# How do I keep PostgreSQL connection open?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

So basicly I create my db client like this:

```
client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();
```

but after some time of innactivity on the db, the clients probably drops the connection and gives me this error:

```
"Error: read ECONNRESET"
```

I tried doing this to keep it open:

```
db.client.on('error', function(e){        
    db.client.connect();
});
```

But that doesn't work and I still get the error. Anyone dealt with this before and has any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Can't you just use the default connection pool that node-postgres provides instead?

Comment: I use both, but you cannot use the pool to do transactions.

Comment: Your solution is to use a proper connection pool, specifically pgbouncer or pgpool-II.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're probably encountering issues with connections being dropped due to expiry of NAT connection tracking tables or similar.

Enable TCP keepalives, either [server-side](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html) or if your client supports it, client-side.

If you can't use TCP keepalives you could instead send empty queries, i.e. send the empty string as a query. This is valid and legal in PostgreSQL and will force a round-trip between client and server but won't add any noise to the logs.